# Is it possible to make initial state empty object in React?

Tags: reactjs

Each time I'm dealing with internal component state in React I must first define empty object for state property or else I will get runtime errors throwing `this.state is undefined`

If I was about to do this:

```
render() {
  const { someProperty } = this.state;

  render <div>{someProperty}</div>
}
```

I'm gonna get error.

But the cure is quite simple:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {};
}
```

However this is very annoying to do this over and over for each component that I create.

Is it somehow possible to force react add initial state as an empty object globally as to avoid all the boilerplate for empty state definition?

P.s. (maybe rhetorical question) Why isn't this done in the same React core?

Comment: The answer to your question is that of initial state.

If you access something on the state then you, as the developer, is supposed to supply that initial state. This might be tedious but it serves a higher purpose, it's explicit and clear what your component is supposed to render.

Comment: »Why isn't this done in the same React core?« Because not every component requires state. In fact I'd argue that in a healthy application, *most* components don't require state.

Comment: By the way, one thing you could do is `const { x } = this.state || {}`, although that effectively leads to more duplication of the empty object than just doing `state = {}` once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to force react add initial state as an empty object globally as to avoid all the boilerplate for empty state definition?

You could create your own »component base class« extending from `React.Component` which implements this and then derive all of your components from this class instead.

```
import { React } from 'react';

class StatefulComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {};
    }
}

export default StatefulComponent;
```

.

```
class MyComponent extends StatefulComponent {
    render() {
        const { something } = this.state;
        return (<div>Hello, {something}</div>);
    }
}
```

([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/WnEK96YNW))

Typically extending components in React is discouraged as it's not idiomatic; and really no harm in adding `this.state = {}` in (every) component that requires state. But if you want to go that route, you can do it.

> P.s. (maybe rhetorical question) Why isn't this done in the same React core?

Because many (or most) components don't require state, thus you'd be allocating wasted memory. This has been discussed in [react#1851](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1851):

> syranide: For components that don't need state (which could easily be the majority), avoiding an allocation is a win.

Answer (score 3):

**Destructuring values that are not an object, array, or iterable**

When you try to use destructuring on null or undefined, you get a type error:

```
var {data} = null;
// TypeError: null has no properties

var {property} = this.state
// TypeError: state is not defined
```

So you could instead do

```
   const { someProperty } = this.state || {};
```

However its even better to defined an initial state since its just one time.